# read icollection data using LINQ in C# code

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to get Icollection data along with other data for each record instance using Linq query which I am doing right.

### Course Model

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

### Student Model

```
   public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

### StudentCourse Model

```
public partial class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentCourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

### Method reading record

```
   public void readStudents()
    {
        using (var db2 = new MyDbContext())
        {
            List<Student> _studentRead = new List<Student>();

            _studentRead = (from b in db2.Students
                            orderby b.StudentID
                            select b).ToList() ;

        }
    }
```

### class model

```
 public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

### 3rd part of question

I am getting correct result now which is; I can see students and list of coursesID in which they are register to using following statement;

```
  using (var db2 = new MyDbContext())
        {
            List<Student> _studentRead = new List<Student>();

            _studentRead = (from _student in db2.Students.Include(r=>r.StudentCourses)        
                            select _student).ToList();
        }
```

Now how can I include courses title to my this linq statement if I want to as below diagram shows I can read courseIDs

[image]

Comment: What's the question? You say what you need, not where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to load the collection of StudentCourse when loading a student object you could just use the Include extension method.

```
public void LoadStudents()
{
  using (var db2 = new MyDbContext()
  {
    //Lambda Linq
    var studentList = new List<Student>();
    studentList = db2.Students
                     .Include(s => s.StudentCourses)
                     .OrderBy (s => s.StudentId)
                     .ToList();

    //Comprehension Linq 
    var compList = new List<Student>();
    compList = (from s in db2.Students.Include(r => r.StudentCourses)
               OrderBy s.StudentId
               Select s).ToList();
  }
}
```

This will explictly tell the context to load the collection when loading each student object from the context.
The extension method is in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace

More information can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Upate 1 - To show loading of multiple levels of dependant objects

```
public void LoadStudents()
{
  //Lambda Linq
  var lambdaList = db2.Students
                      .Include(s => s.StudentCourses.Select(sc => sc.Course))
                      .OrderBy(s => s.StudentId)
                      .ToList();

 //Comprehension Linq
 var compList = (from student in db2.Students.Include(s => s.StudentCourse.Select(sc => sc.Course)
                 OrderBy student.StudentId
                 Select student).ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: This is using linq. However it was using the lambda linq syntax. I have updated my answer to include a solution using comprehension linq syntax

Comment: I am getting following error;    cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Ensure that you have the entity framework referenced and ha e added the using statement. Otherwise the function will expect the string name of the property which you want to include.

Comment: many thanks, I have managed to run however If I want to course title which from different table followed by different model, how can I include that... I have update my question under section 3rd part of question...

Comment: Can you add a model of your Student Course and the model of the entity that you are trying to include to add clarity to your question. Thanks

Comment: no the both models are different i.e. models are 1- student 2-studentCourses 3-Courses

Comment: no I am struggling to add Course model in LINQ Query --> include --> StudentCourse!

Comment: Can you add both model descriptions to your question please.

Comment: I have added student, course and studentcourse model in my question, please refer above!

Comment: Are there properties to the StudentCourse Class which you are not showing, which can only be found here ? If no, then you can remove this object and link the Student and the course directly as a many to many relationship

Comment: no I don't have any properties in studentCourse but as I coming from code first existing database paradigm ...how I approach to this, secondly I doing this exercise purely to understand these concept so my question is also what if I have extra attributes in studentCourse table???

Comment: I have updated my answer. For more information on Many-to-Many relationships I suggest you either research\Ask a new question.